# Gettting frozen error after iterating with each_char in String class. Any fixes?

Tags: ruby, string

```
# Character Counter
class String
  def count_char
    @lcase_count ,@upcase_count, @num_count, @spl_char_count = [0, 0 ,0 ,0]
    each_char { |char|
      if ('a'..'z').cover?(char)
        @lcase_count += 1
      elsif ('A'..'Z').cover?(char)
        @upcase_count += 1
      elsif ('0'..'9').cover?(char)
        @num_count += 1
      else
        @spl_char_count += 1
      end
      }
    return @lcase_count,@upcase_count,@num_count,@spl_char_count
  end
end

input = ARGV[0]

if ARGV.empty?
  puts 'Please provide an input'
  exit
end

puts 'Lowercase characters = %d' % [input.count_char[0]]
puts 'Uppercase characters = %d' % [input.count_char[1]]
puts 'Numeric characters = %d' % [input.count_char[2]]
puts 'Special characters = %d' % [input.count_char[3]]
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from new.rb:25:in `<main>'
new.rb:3:in`count_char': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)

I think as far, i didnt modify string not sure why getting FrozenError

Comment: You did not say which one is the offending line (25). As a first glance, the only String object which is frozen in your code is the one pointed to by `input`. But I don't see that you would modify it anywhere.

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but you are calling method `count_char` 4 times. Once is enough.

Comment: @user1934428 Attempting to set instance variables on a frozen string is the error: `"foo".freeze.instance_variable_set("@lcase_count", 0)`

Comment: @Amadan: I noticed it immediately after I posted my comment, and hence wrote this in my answer. Still, I think the OP should be told that in an error like this, he should also point out which one is the offending line. Would it be better to delete my comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following,

```
class String
  def count_char
    chars = { lcase_count: 0 ,upcase_count: 0, num_count: 0, spl_char_count: 0 }
    each_char do |char|
      if ('a'..'z').cover?(char)
        chars[:lcase_count] += 1
      elsif ('A'..'Z').cover?(char)
        chars[:upcase_count] += 1
      elsif ('0'..'9').cover?(char)
        chars[:num_count] += 1
      else
        chars[:spl_char_count] += 1
      end
    end
    return chars
  end
end

str = 'Asdssd'
# => "Asdssd" 
str.count_char
# => {:lcase_count=>5, :upcase_count=>1, :num_count=>0, :spl_char_count=>0} 
str.count_char[:upcase_count]
# => 1
```

Comment: It works , but i am not sure what was wrong with my code

Answer (score 2):

You are monkeypatching the String class **and** at the same time introduce new instance variables to `String`, which already is a terrible design decision, because - unless you are the author of the String class -, you don't know whether or not these variables exist already. Then, in your code, you modify the variables by incrementing them. Since ARGV is an array of frozen strings, you get the error.

Using instance variables here is absolutely unnecessary. Just use normal local variables.

Answer (score 1):

It’s impossible to tell what exactly is wrong with your code, it looks like one of the instance variables you use is initialized as string or likewise. Introducing instance variables in foreign classes is not a good practice in general, also you do abuse `each` for reducing. Here is an idiomatic ruby code for your task:

```rb
class String
  def count_char
    each_char.with_object(
      {lcase_count: 0, upcase_count: 0, num_count: 0, spl_char_count: 0}
    ) do |char, acc|
      case char
      when 'a'..'z' then acc[:lcase_count] += 1
      when 'A'..'Z' then acc[:upcase_count] += 1 
      when '0'..'9' then acc[:num_count] += 1
      else acc[:spl_char_count] += 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Please note, that this code deals with a simple latin alphabet only. Better approach would be to match regular expressions, like:

```rb
lcase_count = scan(/\P{Lower}/).count
upcase_count = scan(/\P{Upper}/).count
...
```

Comment: Attempting to set instance variables on a frozen string is the error: `"foo".freeze.instance_variable_set("@lcase_count", 0)`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a document regarding ARGV being a frozen string.

But it seems to be that is the case.


You can use [dup](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/dup) to fix your error.

```
input = ARGV[0].dup
```

Comment: They are, though I think this should be documented better. See the discussion [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12128).